# Grouped Counting?

Tags: mysql, sql

i got a table full of user_ids like this:

```
120
95952
2827
5873
38838
332
111
```

Some of them are multiple times inside the table.

I use this query actually:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS amount
FROM `users`
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

This lists all users inluding the amount of records inside the table.

But what i really need: A statistic that says how often the users totally are in the table.

Something like this:

```
1 time inside the table | 1873 users
2 times inside the table | 388 users
3 times inside the table | 98 users
```

etc.

Is this possible with one query? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 5):

Aggregate the current result:

```
select amount, count(*)
from
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS amount
    FROM `users`
    GROUP BY user_id
) dt
group by amount
order by amount
```

Comment: Great! Thank you jarlh! This is the 100% version i wanted :-)